# C++ Update Chart on Buttonclick

Tags: c++, button, charts, refresh

I just started working with C++ on Visual Studio 2010.
I have a Chart and two Buttons.
The number of clicks on each Button will be counted (b1 and b2) and (directly) shown on the Chart.
I got it working, but is there a more simple/efficent way to do it?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            b1++;
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->Clear();
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->AddXY("Button 1", b1);
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->AddXY("Button 2", b2);
         }

private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            b2++;
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->Clear();
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->AddXY("Button 1", b1);
            this->chart1->Series["Count"]->Points->AddXY("Button 2", b2);
         }
```

Thanks for any Answers!

Comment: Is that a read only collection? If not you can just change it directly without having to recreate it. This is really off-topic though, read msdn! And use better names <.<

Comment: thats the point. i cant find any working solution about "updating" or "refreshing" for this.